# Using Mongoose and Node.js search collection and return each unique category

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm making a directory site using mongoose, express and node. Each listing in the database has a city and a country, I would like to create a sitemap type page listing every country, and city that has an item in the database.

So for each unique country in the database - list that country, for each unique city in that country, list that city.

I cannot find a solution to this that isn't totally nuts, what am I missing?

*Bonus Round: it would be nice to count how many listings are in each city.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use aggregate function with group command where you can also specify your condition.
for example(in sales database): The following aggregation operation specifies a group _id of null, calculating the total price and the average quantity as well as counts for all documents in the collection:

```
db.sales.aggregate(
       [
          {
            $group : {
               _id : null,
               totalPrice: { $sum: { $multiply: [ "$price", "$quantity" ] } },
               averageQuantity: { $avg: "$quantity" },
               count: { $sum: 1 }
            }
          }
       ]
)
```

here you can use country instead of _id to group docs by country name or 
see this link, there are some examples also given
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/

Comment: Thank you for this, it led me to the answer. Aggregate followed by $out